# limit(10) in Mongoid 3 / Moped executes count() on entire collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, mongodb, mongoid, mongoid3

I have an action which does a simple query which executes quickly, but for some reason it also executes a `count()` command, which I didn't ask for:

In the controller:

```
@things = Thing.active.where(city: "New York", state: "New York).limit(10).desc(:qs)
```

And in the logs:

```
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 QUERY        database=dirot_development collection=things selector={"$query"=>{"status"=>"available", "city"=>"New York", "state"=>"New York"}, "$orderby"=>{"qs"=>-1}} flags=[:slave_ok] limit=10 skip=0 fields=nil (3.8438ms)
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 KILL_CURSORS cursor_ids=[3455573564096875000] (0.0620ms)
MOPED: 127.0.0.1:27017 COMMAND      database=dirot_development command={:count=>"things", :query=>{"status"=>"available", "city"=>"New York", "state"=>"New York"}} (378.4430ms)
```

As you can see from the log, doing the count takes **378ms** while actually getting the 10 documents that I want takes barely **4ms**. How can I eliminate the count?

I am using will_paginate, but not in this particular action/view.

Any ideas?

*** UPDATE ***
Active is just a standard scope: `scope :active, where(status: "available")`

Comment: Can you show your `.active` method?

Comment: It's just `scope :active, where(status: "available")`